# How do I approach a candidate for a bounty whose answer needs amendments?

Tags: discussion, edits, bounty, etiquette

A week ago, I started a bounty on a question. It got a couple of answers, and I consider one of those answers to be a candidate for receiving the bounty award. However, despite being mostly correct, in my opinion, the answer is wrong about some details. I provided a comment with my thoughts (suggestions for improvement), but the author of the answer never came back to adjust his answer.

<sup>(Originally, this question was about [this specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73460728) and [Soumya Mahunt's answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73519172/). However, the situation has changed; Soumya has edited his answer. That does not invalidate the more general etiquette question about how similar cases should be handled.)</sup>

I don't think it's correct to reward an answer which contains some misconceptions, but, if those mistakes were fixed, I think this answer would deserve the bounty.

Am I supposed to turn a blind eye to what I perceive as flaws and award the bounty to the answer anyway? Or, should I edit the answer myself, even without any indication of agreement from the answer's original author? I would appreciate any advice on the situation.

Comment: If you want the award the bounty is completely up to you, and if you don't think that the answer is good/correct enough to award it, then it is your prerogative to not award it. I personally don't think we should be telling you *what* you should do with it, as it's a little like telling you what to do with your votes. Note that if you do nothing, and the scores remain the same, the bounty won't be awarded at all. If they change (and you don't accept any of the answers) half will be awarded to the answer with a score >= 2 (oldest wins tiebreaks).

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the input. I understand that it's up to me to decide, but what about editing it myself to meet my own requirements? Is it considered acceptable?

Comment: If you feel you are improving the answer, and not conflicting with the OP's intents, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You did what you could at this point - left a comment for the author to address. Since they haven't returned yet, you, as a member of the community are free to edit their post as long as the edit preserves the original intent (generally speaking). Don't forget that all posts here are public contributions licensed by CC-BY-SA, which allows free modification by everyone. If the author comes back and rolls back your edit, you can take from there.

Comment: Regardless of the bounty: all you can do to contact someone is to leave them a comment, since you don't have any other contact details on them. If they mention contact details on their profile (this person has added their twitter and GitHub profiles), you could try that.

Comment: @Adriaan I would really avoid contacting people outside SO for a SO post, I have a feeling not many would like that. I would save it for exceptional occasions.

Comment: I would actually disagree that people wouldn't like it if their details are on their profile page, @MarcoBonelli ; they have put them there so they can be contacted. On the other hand, I don't blame people who completely ignore messages from people on things like LinkedIn, when they *don't* share those details.

Comment: @Larnu I don't think that linking any social media on my profile should be interpreted as "contact me in private here for your SO question". In the same way it does not mean "contact me in private here" on any other platform where you link other platforms. It's just a link for whoever wants to know more about you. You think people like Jon Skeet are linking their twitter to be messaged privately? PS: not saying that I dislike people contacting me, but I just don't think that's most people's intend purpose for those links, and I don't think you can assume that without any hint.

Comment: I do not doubt that people message Jon Skeet on Twitter about their questions, @MarcoBonelli , if he links to it on his profile.

Comment: *it's a little like telling you what to do with your votes* This is customary behaviour in some counties. We should not interfere with people's right to deny other people rights. That would be oppression.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the close reason used here. We don't typically close [specific-*] questions just because the status of the post has changed. e.g. a meta question asking why a post on main is deleted is not closed as "not reproducible" just because the post was undeleted on main. Voting to reopen this.

Comment: Not only that, @cigien, but this is a *generally* interesting/relevant question, even if it's not linked to a specific answer. Maybe I shouldn't even have added that tag.

Comment: There's a suggestion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147386/282094 - they didn't answer your inquiry, so don't award the bounty; after it expires edit their answer and accept it, if they rollback then unaccept. Since it's not your question then accepting isn't an option, so just leave it unawarded.

Comment: On the subject of anyone contacting someone outside of the platform, if I were to be contacted, I would ignore them and probably end of deleting whatever caused then to contact me out of spite. Just because I have a social account linked doesn’t mean it’s there for you to reach out to me. Stack Exchange isn’t a social platform, my social accounts are linked, for reasons beyond helping an individual on the platform.

Comment: @SecurityHound *"...probably end of deleting whatever caused then to contact me out of spite."* Ehh, that's not really appropriate. If your reason for deleting the content is you're angry at someone, then that's vandalism, not a valid reason for deletion. Please don't do that. Otherwise, everything you said is 100% true and I would endorse it. If someone is *repeatedly* harassing you off-site, consider raising a moderator flag. (But I wouldn't bother for a single attempt to contact. It's unlikely we'd do anything. Just ignore it and hope they get the hint. I sure do!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think you should approach it any differently than you would handle any other answer that needs amendments: add a comment explaining where the answer needs improvement.

There is no moral/ethical problem in awarding the bounty if you point out the problems in a comment. I think it's still a legitimate reward for the effort put into answering the question, even if that answer has some flaws.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think it's correct to reward an answer which contains some misconceptions, but, at the same time, I think this answer deserves the bounty.

I don't understand that edited part. It seems like you are on the edge here. On the one hand you say this answer deserves the bounty, on the other hand you say that this answer contains misconceptions and therefore should not be rewarded. Both is impossible at the same time. It may though be a case exactly on the boundary between deserves the bounty and doesn't deserve the bounty. In that case it will be a tough decision but you or the system (it's good to know the rules there (see Larnu's comment)) will resolve the bounty in some way.

However if you want to say that the answer does not deserve a reward without your edits well then simply to not give the reward. But take into account that without the answer you couldn't have done the edits either, so it helped. Some kind of reward might still be in order. And because a bounty cannot be handed out only partially you have to decide and either pay it out fully or none at all. Both seems reasonable here. It's your call.

> Am I supposed to turn a blind eye to what I perceive as flaws and award the bounty to the answer anyway? Or, should I edit the answer myself, even without any indication of agreement from the answer's original author? I would appreciate any advice on the situation.

Do not turn a blind eye to flaws. You commented but if the answerer already moved on, then editing in order to improve content is one of the most common actions on StackOverflow. In my eyes, it's just fine although some people might be critical if you add/change too much and prefer that you post major alterations as their own answer. It could be that you actually introduce misconceptions by your own.

But there is no obligation to edit. So simply choose either of editing and rewarding the bounty to the original author of the answer or not editing and awarding or not awarding the bounty. It's all up to you and what you feel is the best.

I, personally, would go for the edit (as long as it's reasonable) and the award because that should result in the highest quality content possible.

Comment: The text of the first quote was actually "_I don't think it's correct to reward an answer which contains some misconceptions, but without it I think this answer deserved the bounty._" it was later edited to generalize the question.

Comment: I think the point of the first quote is that *after the changes* it would deserve the bounty. So the OP would in part award the bounty for their own work of fixing the answer.

Comment: Ironically, perhaps this highlights the difficulty of editing a post, even when one has the purest of intentions to preserve the author's original intent. I did not intend to change the meaning in any way when I made the edit to that sentence. However, I'll admit that the turn of phrase "at the same time" was entirely my own invention. Do you or @AbdulAzizBarkat think that edit actually changed the meaning of the sentence, compared to the original phrasing, "without it"? Clearly, "without it" meant "without the edits/improvements that I would make to correct the misconceptions".

Comment: @CodyGray Wasn't aware of the edit. Have added something here to cover all possibilities. "at the same time" for me means "and" but I'm not an original English speaker (only started at age 13 learning it), so misunderstandings can happen at any time.

Comment: @CodyGray in my case I believe "without it" means "without those misconceptions" or "overlooking those misconceptions".

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat is correct. English is also not my first language, and I'm sorry if the sentence was misleading, however the meaning I intended to put into my words is that without the misconceptions, I would give the reward straight away.

Comment: Yeah, I see where the misunderstanding occurred. Thanks for clarifying your intended meaning, @TheDreamsWind. I've undone my incorrect edit. Sorry about that! Note that none of this should be taken to imply that anyone's English skills are deficient. Communicating clearly is difficult, even when one has a near-perfect mastery of the language.